# Pasar una variable a un widget, modificar esa variable en el nuevo widget y regresar su nuevo valor

Tags: flutter, dart

Declaro una variable "score=0" en SoundPage, después quiero pasar ese valor a SoundItem y ahí modificarlo, para después regresar ese valor a SoundPage.

```
class SoundItem extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Data> sounds;
  final int index;
  final int aux;
  final int score;

  SoundItem({this.sounds, this.index, this.aux, this.score});

  @override
  _SoundItemState createState() => _SoundItemState();
}
```

Aquí intento utilizarlo, pero me marca **'score' can't be used as a setter because it is final.
Try finding a different setter, or making 'score' non-final.** y quito el final en SoundItem pero me imprime en consola **score _SoundItemState#aefad.widget.score** y yo requiero un número.

```
void review(){
    switch(value){
      case 0:{
        if(this.widget.sounds[widget.index+widget.aux].left.title==this.widget.sounds[widget.index+widget.aux].right.title)
          this.widget.score+=1;
      }break;
      case 1:{
        if(this.widget.sounds[widget.index+widget.aux].left.title!=this.widget.sounds[widget.index+widget.aux].right.title)
          this.widget.score+=1;
      }break;
    }

    print("score $this.widget.score");
  }
```

Y no he logrado tener ese score y regresarlo a SoundPage.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías dejar la variable score como **int** únicamente e imprimir el valor del siguiente modo:

```
var scorevalue= widget.score.toString();
print("score $scorevalue");
```

Comment: Si mira, en mi página Item tengo mi variable score, cuando la paso a Home y la imprimo me manda null. En home la paso final int score Home({this.score}) no se porque no está tomando el valo que le paso.

Comment: pero la variable score es "final int" y si vas a modificarla tiene que ser "int" y usar el código que pasé para imprimirlo bien